# How to add custom option "input-box" for particular attribute set in Magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, input

Am having one category called Cakes in my website. I have added custom option for each one product separately, but I want add that custom option for all commonly for all cake products in simple and configurable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you'll create new attribute then you'll see this option in under properties (Catalog Input Type for Store Owner), you can select whatever you want.

Comment: This will give input text field for product in admin panel but I need text-box in user side to get the message for product @Wajahat Bashir

Comment: i think you want to show on single product details page ? right
and you want to received message from user about that product ?
@GowriShankar

Comment: Yeah Its about cake order. I want to get the message to be write on cake from the user who is going to buy. Adding custom option for all proucts is not possible. So any other way?@Wajahat Bashir

Comment: @GowriShankar, Please see both screenshot, then you'll follow these steps.
1) https://prnt.sc/gerzai 2) https://prnt.sc/gerzj6
just add 1 button on product view page, when you'll click on that then he'll send you those details whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Its fine but am looking for different one. If I added one custom option with text-field in a product, it will be display in product page. I need same like that. Is there anyway to use custom option for multiple products without creating seperately@Wajahat Bashir

Comment: I think, then you create text box form on product details page. don't go for popup etc. direct you can show on product details page or whatever you want. understand what i want to saying you. ?

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to do that. Am totally new to magento.

Comment: ahan, then plz first little bit study and understand code then you'll open view.phtml on this path (app/design/frontend/your-package/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml) and creat your form